# JavaScript Class Definition in Multiple Files

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript. I come from a C# background. In C#, there is the concept of partial classes. In other words, a way to split the definition of a class across files. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Currently, I have a directory structure like this:

```
/
  MyClass.js
  child-folder
    MyClassAdditions.js
```

**MyClass.js**

```
function MyClass() {
}
```

Is there a way to add additional functions to MyClass from `MyClassAdditions.js`? If so, how?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes; you'll find the answer if you google for "javascript prototype."

Comment: Also, `module.exports` suggests that you're using Node.js. If so, you should mention it in the question because Node and browsers handle files differently.

Comment: @Juhana I've updated the question to remove `module.exports`. I want to use this code in the browser. I'm basing my implementation off info found [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Comment: Uh, chapter 1.2 of that article shows how to add stuff to the object afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extend properly a JS object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975408/how-can-i-extend-properly-a-js-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2018-05-21 - JavaScript now has formal classes, and the syntax looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
  }
  // This is the same as MyClass.prototype.printParams
  printPrams() {
    console.log("The value of param1 is", this.param1);
  }
}
```

**Original answer from 2015:**

While JS currently doesn't have *formal* classes, you can create constructor objects which can get instantiated. You can even extend these objects or add onto them later. Here's a simple example:

```
// create your constructor
var MyClass = function(param1) {
    // create instance properties here
    this.param1 = param1;
};

// all instances of your class will point to the constructors prototype
MyClass.prototype.printParams = function () {
    console.log("The value of param1 is", this.param1);
};

// lets create two instances so we can see how the prototype thing works
var foo = new MyClass("foo");
var bar = new MyClass("bar");

foo.printParams(); // => The value of param1 is foo
bar.printParams(); // => The value of param1 is bar

foo.param1 = "oof";
foo.printParams(); // => The value of param1 is oof

// Now, lets change how printParams works.
// Remember, we still have instances of foo and bar already created.
// Since they both point to their constructors prototype, you 
// can change things later... at any time.
MyClass.prototype.printParams = function () {
    console.log("PARAM1 SAID WHAT??", this.param1);
};
MyClass.prototype.sayNothing = function () {
    console.log("nothing");
};

// All instances get these new methods, yay prototypal inheritance
foo.printParams(); // => PARAM1 SAID WHAT?? oof
bar.printParams(); // => PARAM1 SAID WHAT?? bar
foo.sayNothing(); // => nothing
bar.sayNothing(); // => nothing

// Lets say we want foo to have it's own sayNothing method, 
// you can define one on the instance itself - not really cool, but doable
foo.sayNothing = function () {
    console.log("nothing at all");
    // If you want to be cool, you can call the shared prototype method too
    this.constructor.prototype.sayNothing.call(this);
};

// bar is still going to use the method defined on the prototype
// while foo will have its own implementation of sayNothing
foo.sayNothing(); // => nothing at all
                  // => nothing
bar.sayNothing(); // => nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have had similar problem I recommend this way which I think you can find nowhere, I found every part in a separated document:

1. When loading your main js file, you define the class MyClass():

***`MyClass = {}`***

2. Then in your `MyClass.js` file which is supposed to deal with laptop info, you can define some functions and properties like this:

```
MyClass.laptop = {
        brand : "Dell",
        model: "1525",
        color: "silver",
        getBrandAndModel: function(){
            return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + MyClass.laptop.model;
        },
        getBrandAndColor: function(){
            return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + MyClass.laptop.color;
        },
        colorizeIt: function(colorName){
            return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + colorName;
        }
     }
```

3. Now in the `MyClassAdditions.js` which you are going to deal with cellphone info you go like this:

```
MyClass.cellphone = {
    brand : "Samsung",
    color: "Black",
    width: 8,
    height: 15,
    getDimention: function(){
        return MyClass.cellphone.width + " * " + MyClass.cellphone.height;
    },
 }
```

in this way, you have added two parts in two separated js files into an object named **MyClass**.

Now test this examples to make sure it really works:

```js
        MyClass.laptop.brand  //"Dell"
        MyClass.laptop.getBrandAndColor() //"Dell, silver"
        MyClass.cellphone.color //"Black"
        MyClass.cellphone.getDimention() //"8 * 15"
```

It's like you have created following object in the first place:

```js
      MyClass = {
        laptop : {
            brand : "Dell",
            model: "1525",
            color: "silver",
            getBrandAndModel: function(){
                return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + MyClass.laptop.model;
            },
            getBrandAndColor: function(){
                return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + MyClass.laptop.color;
            },
            colorizeIt: function(colorName){
                return MyClass.laptop.brand + ", " + colorName;
            }
         },
         cellphone :{
            brand : "Samsung",
            color: "Black",
            width: 8,
            height: 15,
            getDimention: function(){
                return MyClass.cellphone.width + " * " + MyClass.cellphone.height;
            },
         }
      }
```

By the way you can delete a part of object by the keyword `delete` like this:

```js
    delete  MyClass.cellphone
```

now `MyClass.cellphone` returns `undefined` while `MyClass.laptop` returns object.